# How to transform images directly uploaded to S3 from a Heroku node app?

Tags: amazon-web-services, heroku, amazon-s3

I have an app where I'm allowing users to upload images. I'm working on having them upload images [directly to AWS S3](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3-upload-node), rather than a pass-through (sounds like it really ties up your Heroku dynos if done using pass through). However, I would like to perform transformations to the assets they upload (for example, re-sizing, compressing image quality to reduce file size and creating thumbnail versions). Since the files are being directly uploaded to S3, I can't perform any transformations until they are finished uploading to Amazon.

I'm not sure of the best way to handle this, but I'm thinking:

1. User uploads an image through a file input form field that is directly uploaded to S3.
2. Once that is successfully completed, that image url from Amazon is saved to my Heroku database.
3. Then, I can take that image and perform all those transformations to it.
4. Re-uploading the image to S3 as cropped, compressed and thumbnailed version.
5. Persisting the url for the new edited images in my Heroku database.

Is this the best workflow to solve this problem, or is there a more efficient solution? Thanks!

Comment: Yes this is the correct and best practice work flow you are following. Check this article too they too follow the same work flow. https://aws.amazon.com/articles/PHP/1602 only it is for PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some alternatives to re-processing the pictures in Heroku:

**Image processing with AWS Lambda**

Configure your Amazon S3 bucket to trigger an AWS Lambda function when a picture is uploaded. The Lambda function could transform the image automatically.

See: [Tutorial: Using AWS Lambda with Amazon S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example.html)

**Transform pictures upon retrieval**

Instead of transforming and storing the images, use an online service that can transform the images on-demand, eg:

- [Cloudinary](http://cloudinary.com/)
- [Imgix](http://imgix.com/)

Comment: Thanks John! I had no idea that this service was provided. It seems like a simpler, more pleasant solution for what I'm trying to accomplish so will give these two a try. Thanks again.